# Finding range of a equation with given condition.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

We are given three real number $$a,b,c$$. With the condition $$(a^2+1)(b^2+1)(c^2+1)=9$$
We have to find the number of integers in the range of $$(ab+bc+ca)$$

Ans given is 7.

Comment: I tried by factorisation like 331,911,etc.. I checked by finding different values of a,b,c accordingly . l I got 3 integers -2,2,0. But answer is demanding 4 more.

Comment: do you mind putting your attempt along with the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(a^2+1)(b^2+1)(c^2+1)=((a+b)^2+(ab-1)^2)(c^2+1)=(ab+bc+ca-1)^2+(a+b+c-abc)^2$

Comment: Can u please explain how we will go further now.

Comment: isn't that obvious? $(ab+bc+ca-1)^2 \le 9$

Comment: Not quite. You've found a necessary condition $(ab+bc+ca-1)^2 \leq 9$, but have not yet shown that is truly the image. EG It's also true that $(ab+bc+ca-1)^2 \leq 100^2$, but that doesn't mean that every value is attainable. So this is fine as a hint, but not quite a complete solution.